# SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created an intranet site that is running fine locally but when running with IIS I am getting a SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\username' message. Not sure if it matters or not but I am remotely connecting the server from a different location. 
I was hesitant to post as I am quite new to programming and feared looking silly but I have searched for days and days looking for a way to fix this. I have checked Windows authentication over and over as well as windows authorization.

Note: When logging in for windows authentication, If I enter the incorrect user details, the window appears again, if user details correct I can access the site. I can then navigate my way around the site until a point required to access the database. Looking forward to a resolution. Currently pulling my hair out.

Can supply code if requried

Comment: Can you share how you set up the connection. in particular how you set the username and password

Comment: As far as I am aware the username and Password are being set in the Active Directory, sorry I should have mentioned that we have approximately 500 employees that will be using the site.

Comment: sure, but in your app, when you connect to SQL, what do you specify?  When you run locally, if you use trusted_connection=yes, it will take your userid.  If you're running under IIS, you need to login to sql as a user with appropriate access.  That may mean you need to get the user id of the intraweb app user.

Comment: can you post your connection string?

Comment: Data Source=auvidnwi02; Initial Catalog=Dandenong; Integrated Security=True

Comment: When I first started the site, I had a work mate that helped me at the start and he knew a lot more about sql than I do. He has since left unfortunately so I haven't changed any of that since it was working.